# HTTP header to force HTTP/1.1 when using HTTPS

Tags: http, https, http-headers, http-1.1

I cannot find this information anywhere, since all questions are library specific or are about forcing use of HTTP/2.

> Is it possible to set (force) the HTTP version to HTTP/1.1 via headers when connecting to a server using HTTPS?

I have read that servers set the HTTP version to HTTP/2 by default when using HTTPS, but that HTTPS does **not** necessarily depend on HTTP/2.

I ask because I am connecting to an end server that uses HTTPS but the server only supports HTTP/1.1 (possibly connecting via an intermediary server that supports HTTP/2).

I know you can force curl to use HTTP1.1 using a flag but I am not sure if curl sets something in the headers or does something at a lower level.

```
--http1.1
```

I can access the end server successfully using curl when using the `--http1.1` flag. Without the flag, the request fails.

Ideally, I want to use other solutions other than curl to connect to the end server.

Comment: The http version has nothing to do with flags or low level networking. It is sent as plain text in each request: `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1`.